# Sqlite4Java on Raspberry PI not finding ARM.so file

Tags: java, linux, sqlite, raspberry-pi

Can someone please help me, i am trying to get my project to run on my Raspberry PI and i am getting an error.  I believe it aint loading the libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so file

Here is the output from the command

```
java -jar sqlite4java.jar -d
```

OUTPUT

```
sqlite4java 282
140919:155005.232 FINE [sqlite] Internal: loading library
140919:155005.255 FINE [sqlite] Internal: java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/arm:/lib:/usr/lib
140919:155005.259 FINE [sqlite] Internal: sqlite4java.library.path=null
140919:155005.261 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cwd=/home/pi/.
140919:155005.264 FINE [sqlite] Internal: default path=/home/pi
140919:155005.267 FINE [sqlite] Internal: forced path=null
140919:155005.271 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.name=linux; os=linux
140919:155005.274 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.arch=arm
140919:155005.282 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-arm from /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so
140919:155005.291 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-arm from /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
140919:155005.296 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-arm
140919:155005.304 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-arm: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-linux-arm in java.library.path
140919:155005.307 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux
140919:155005.313 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-linux in java.library.path
140919:155005.315 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java
140919:155005.321 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java in java.library.path
140919:155005.324 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-arm-d
140919:155005.336 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-arm-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-linux-arm-d in java.library.path
140919:155005.343 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-d
140919:155005.355 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-linux-d in java.library.path
140919:155005.358 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-d
140919:155005.375 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-d in java.library.path
Error: cannot load SQLite
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1814)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromPath(Internal.java:337)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:117)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.main(SQLite.java:368)
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

I have downloaded the libsqlite4java-linux-armv7a.so and libsqlite4java-linux-armv5te.so file from the downloads page here https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/downloads/list

I have transferred both files (separately) on to my PI and run the above command, and i get the same output.  I have renamed each file to libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so and still no luck.

I find this part of the error message a bit wierd, not sure if this has something to do with it, although have no idea why it is happening

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: /home/pi/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```